# How to pass value from module to module of different page in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and have a scenario where two pages using 2 modules on each page ie M1 and M2.
Both modules having his own controllers C1 & C2. I want to pass value from C1 to C2. I tried with service but its not working. Can able to set value in first page but get value null on second page.

Can someone point me in the correct direction how to pass values between modules?

Comment: It is not quite clear from your question whether you want to pass values from one controller to the other on the same module or you want to pass value from one module to another

Comment: Need to pass value from controller C1 in module M1 to controller C2 in module M2. Modules are on different page e.g M1, C1 in login page and M2,C2 in home page so after click on login button need to pass value to home page.

Comment: can you make a simplified fiddle with the scenario that you tried with the service?

Comment: How you make the transition between modules? Are you using routes?

Comment: yup, let me know the best way

Comment: If... you need to store some data, from login to others pages, like userId, name, you can to use https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage .

Comment: yeah, can use as alternative localstorage, cookies and query parameter.  like to know if there is a way to pass between pages of diff module or its not possible between different pages having diff module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a dependency of M1 on M2. After that you will be able to access the services of M1 through which you can establish a communication between two controllers.

Comment: tried by injecting M1 into M2, as when click it set the value on M1 service and redirect to home page and also M2 able to access the same service  of function get but the value will be blank. I think when M2 calls service of M1 it create new instance and set value wont get. It will be helpful if you provie example via. plnkr

Answer (score 0):

If it's on a separate pages, you either have to use the server to save the data on Page1 then load it on Page2 or use some sort of local storage on the client side(cookies, localStorage)